# How to add color and legend by points' label one by one in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to divide and color points,val_lab(611,3) by their labels,pred_LAB(611,)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.set_xlabel('L')
ax.set_ylabel('A')
ax.set_zlabel('B')
for i in range(0, len(val_lab)):
    ax.scatter3D(
        val_lab[i,0], 
        val_lab[i,1],
        val_lab[i,2],
        s = 8,
        marker='o',
        c = pred_LAB
        #cmap = 'rainbow'
    )
#ax.legend(*points.legend_elements(), title = 'clusters')  
plt.show()
```

The problem is it shows error,

> c' argument has 611 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x'
> with size 1, 'y' with size 1.

However, if the dataset only have ten points,it can show the figure correctly, I don't know how to solve this problem, besides, how to add legend of this figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution you would want to replace `c = pred_LAB` with `c = pred_LAB[i]`. But you do not have to use a for loop to plot the data. You can just use the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# generate random input data
val_lab = np.random.randint(0,10,(611,3))
pred_LAB = np.random.uniform(0,1, (611,))

# plot data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.set_xlabel('L')
ax.set_ylabel('A')
ax.set_zlabel('B')

# create one 3D scatter plot - no for loop
ax.scatter3D(
    val_lab[:,0], 
    val_lab[:,1],
    val_lab[:,2],
    s = 8,
    marker='o',
    c = pred_LAB,
    cmap = 'rainbow',
    label='my points'
)
# add legend
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I once tried this method without for-loop however, I don't know why it shows the error,ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: masked_array(data=[0.275191, 0.194905, 0.496005, 0.6390076836408018],
             mask=False,
       fill_value='?',
            dtype=object)

Comment: The error you are refering to is a new error that just appeared?

Comment: yes,I use totally same code, but it occurs this error

Comment: There can be different reasons for your error. One can be the shape of colors might be wrong. Another can be you are not using valid RGBA values.

Comment: So is there some way can keep for-loop function...if I show the point one by one, it can work..

Comment: yeah sure just keep the for loop. As I mentioned above there is just one small adjustment